# Django post updates in sidebar

Tags: django-models, django-views

I'm learning Django and have built a small blog. I can go into the admin site and write a post and then have it load in the index.html. I have a sidebar that appears on every page and I want to allow the admin to create an update that consists of an id, author, created_on, and content fields.

Then the side bar would post the latest update.

I have been able to create the Updates model and create new updates in django admin. But I am unable to get those updates to render on the site. I think its an issue with my urls or the views.

Any advice? Thanks!

models.py

```
class Update(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_update')
content = models.TextField(blank=True)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created_on']

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.id} ({self.created_on})' 

def get_absolute_url(self):
    """Returns the URL to access a detail record for this book."""
    return reverse('update_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

views.py

```
def update_details(request):

UpdateContent = Update.objects.order_by('-created_on')[:1]

context = {
    'UpdateContent': UpdateContent,
}

# Render the HTML template sidebar.html with the data in the context variable
return render(request, 'sidebar.html', context=context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.PostList.as_view(),name='home'),
path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
path('update', views.UpdateDetailView, name='update_details')
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I needed to use inclusion tags. Such a simple fix for all the time I spent thinking it was an issue with the views or the urls.

Urls can only be associated with one view was one fact I was trying to work around.

Then I tried adding multiple data to the view for a url but this complicated things and broke other parts of the site and never really worked anyway.

Here is the link to a few articles that helped me with the inclusion tags. Inclusions tags are perfect when you have certain data that needs to appear on many pages of your site.

References:

- [micropyramid](https://micropyramid.com/blog/inclusion-tags/)
- [django inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)
- [pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/create-custom-template-tags-and-filters-in-django)